# The result entity after calling JpaRepository.getById() does not contain values for fields with @JoinColumn after calling JpaRepository.saveAndFlush()

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

When I save an entity that has a `@JoinColumn` field that references another entity, it is saved correctly as expected by calling `saveAndFlush()`. Now, I want to be able to return this entity along with its related entities back to the user. I assumed that calling `getById()` with the ID of the newly saved entity will also retrieve `@JoinColumn` values in the returned entity, however, the related entity of the returned entity contains the exact same values as the related entity that used in `saveAndFlush()`. I have made example code to demonstrate what I'm talking about.

I send request:
`GET http://localhost:8080`
and receive as response:

```json
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "tests",
  "related": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": null
  }
}
```

My goal is to have the same request return the following response:

```json
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "tests",
  "related": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "test"
  }
}
```

Where the `related` contains `name` along with `id` which was specified in the `saveAndFlush()`.

**Controller.java**

```java
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Controller {

    private final ObjectRepository oRepo;
    private final RelatedObjectRepository coRepo;

    @GetMapping
    private Object test() {
        // imagine as if this entity is already present in the database before this request is handled, this line is only for context.
        RelatedObject co = coRepo.saveAndFlush(new RelatedObject(null, "test"));
        
        // create an instance of RelatedObject to contain the value for the related_id foreign key column.
        RelatedObject nco = new RelatedObject(co.getId(), null);
        // create Object and save it along with the referenced RelatedObject.
        Object o = oRepo.saveAndFlush(new Object(null, "tests", nco));

        // I expected all values of 'co' object to be contained in the result here in the @JoinColumn field 'related' of Object, instead, only 'id' is present like the 'nco' object
        return oRepo.getById(o.getId());
    }
}
```

**Object.java**

```java
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Table(name = "object")
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Object {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 100)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "related_id")
    private RelatedObject related;

}
```

**RelatedObject.java**

```java
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Table(name = "related_object")
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RelatedObject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 100)
    private String name;
}
```

**ObjectRepository.java**

```java
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface ObjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Object, Long> {
}
```

**RelatedObjectRepository.java**

```java
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface RelatedObjectRepository extends JpaRepository<RelatedObject, Long> {
}
```

**SpringPlayGroundApplication.java**

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringPlayGroundApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringPlayGroundApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: I am currently overcoming this by ensuring request objects are always mapped to existing entity by using getById() in mapping methods, that way it is returned in the result, but it would be good to know if there is an easy workaround supported by Spring Data JPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured out what I needed.

Associated entities needed to cascade refresh, for example:

```java
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
private Category parent;
```